# nginx with dotnet returning 404 on with https

Tags: c#, nginx, .net-core, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have deployed MERN stack app on Nginx with reverse proxy settings and it's working perfectly. I recently developed dotnet core 6.0 web application and trying to attach with nginx.

I created service to start dotnet application which is as follows

```
Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/webApp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/html/webApp/web-app.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my nginx config for dotnet application

```
server {

    #Path to the React front end
    root /var/www/html/MERNAPI/client/build;

    #the main html file
    index index.html;

    #Enter the IP address of your droplet
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com

     #STORE the nginx access logs for this app here
     access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log;
     #Store the error logs for this app here
     error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log;


    client_max_body_size 64M;
    location / {
        # Without this line routing in your Single Page APP will not work  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    #REST API BACKEND CONFIG
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

#Socket IO Config
location /socket.io {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/socket.io/;
}


    location /EV {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }






    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # man>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # m>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
 server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com

     #STORE the nginx access logs for this app here
     access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Program.cs

```
using MySqlConnector;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ => new MySqlConnection(configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//We set Time here 
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddMvc();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

appsetting.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=123;database=xyz"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When  I try to access with on my domain it shows 404 page can’t be found (This domain runs on HTTPS) and it have certbot's SSL certificate. But when on other fresh server I've installed dotnet and nginx it works perfectly on port HTTP. I don't know what's wrong with my nginx or dotnet configuration. Please somebody advice me what to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. You need to post more contents of your nginx config file. 2. `http://127.0.0.1:5000` should be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` as the ending `/` is critical (read nginx manual for more details). 3. HSTS and HTTP to HTTPS redirection are overkilled here, because you want HTTP connections between nginx and Kestrel/ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thank you Lex. It working now but I got another issue in dev tools it shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at jquery.min.js:1:1) for all Js files and my css is not loading.

Comment: All the Js and CSS file contains html of my MERN app not the dotnet app. don't know what's wrong. I've updated my NGINX config file. Please take a look and suggest what to change.

Comment: @LexLi, I found the issue. My react application is serving on root path location / . So dotnet application is looking for css and js files at my root path and  found index.html so all these files shows index.html instead of wwwroot/js/ files. What should I change to make it work?